# How to delete specific views from TableView cell and get back those views in next cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `TableView` with a custom cell. The cell is having multiple views and labels inside it. Now based on conditions I want to remove views and labels from the cell but in next cell I want them back and remove different set of views and label.

As I am using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so after deleting the views from first cell I am not getting those views in second cell.

I don't want to hide them as I need some auto layout adjustment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `prepareForReuse()` in `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    // add that view back
}
```

Comment: How can I add those views back.Should I have to create and add again programatically ?

Comment: @200OK Year，as you removed them.

Comment: @200OK Try to use two kinds of cell. One has that view,one not.

Comment: I have multiple views. In one cell view1 will come in other cell view2 in other cell view3 in other cell view 4 and view 1 will come. So I can't make different cell for all the use cases.I just want to get a fresh cell after display.

Comment: @200OK reuse is just not to give you a fresh cell.So make it fresh in prepareForReuse

Comment: My question is same.How can I make get a fresh cell from the storyboard cell ?

Answer (score 0):

In custom cell you just add all view and label according to your requirement. In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

you just hide or show view and label according to your need.

Comment: I don't want to add views and labels runtime. As I have set my cell autolayout properly so after removing the views and labels my cell will adjust properly. I can't hide the views as after hiding also views occupy the place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a height constraint for the labels and views that you want to delete and set IBOutlets for the same, and instead of deleting the view from custom cell you could set the height constraint to 0 as per your condition. So the views and labels wont appear in the screen. Hope this will Help you. :)

Comment: My cell is little bit complicated with complex autolayout constraints. So using height constraint will be more complicated. I want to reset the cell after each and every cell display.

Comment: Then a work around can be provided, you could create another custom cell in which you can remove the labels and views which are not needed for the condition and use that custom cell.

Comment: That won't be a good idea as there are 4-5 different set of views and I have to remove them depend on some condition.So in that case there will a lot of cells.

Comment: @Aneesh answer is the best practice for this problem from what I know. I myself normally have "hide" contains, at the height of 0, (or width) and with priority of 1000, and make them active when needed to hide.